# Laravel Homestead automatically destroys VM

Tags: php, laravel, window, homestead

I followed all the instructions on how to setup laravel homestead.

I am using windows 7 and am trying to install laravel homestead on my system.
I have install virtualbox and vagrant.

Every thing seems to go very well however when i run `vagrant up` homestead VM boots up but fail at some point.

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/digitlimit/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Code => C:/server/www
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC0/giyiT0RlisfYwMdHfL7lUSxZtO
kEWX5dJwmwwru5dUQda/xknMa9oHKqAlv//V+VvzQ0JKv4eA3xbCgrlj4NAwoZrEjqVC2P0M3HqT2JKF
M76/WCU4Ki7TQnMQz5ff3aRIqFphNC0LZWXz9v92QjJYohODlOAxIhw94PUimnt3BIzOKxT+kqPuBCOc
+oTJTZwduQsCIb+ArmKVDxNMj1LCL65WrSTaO4CmqqVqiTJ3LkzKm4nNluvy26w5usAKhFs8zrPV0+Jh
DXPI6w9crKzs7y/zSspsENgDdNTuh8wRflUrfGgJMq6LbDVf+Kp6lsjvJMadpn2ABXBY9pr5F emailme@yahoo.com
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
```

I have provided the full bash commands and logs here:

http://pastebin.com/hcKpF9kA

Kindly view the log above and advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now!

I ended up doing a fresh installation of both vagrant and virtualbox. 
I took the following steps:

1.
I uninstalled vagrant and Virtualbox and deleted their folders from my system.
I also deleted the following folders:

```
C:\Users\mysername\.homestead

C:\Users\username\Homestead - vagrant environment
```

2. I deleted all the network adapters install by VM
   Open Virtualbox and click File -> Preferences, click Network tab and then Host-only networks. Click on each item and click delete button

[image]

3. I download and install fresh copies of Vagrant and Virtualbox.
   Am using Windows 7 (32bit)

https://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/vagrant/vagrant_1.7.2.msi

http://dlc-cdn.sun.com/virtualbox/4.3.22/VirtualBox-4.3.22-98236-Win.exe

4. I also download laravel/homestead manually
   https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.2/providers/virtualbox.box

to my downloads folder C:\Downloads\homestead-0-2-2.box

5. After i have install Virtualbox and Vagrant. I installed laravel/homestead by running the following command in git bash (you can download git bash here: http://git-scm.com/downloads).

   vagrant box add laravel/homestead  /c/downloads/homestead-0-2-2.box
6. Then i downloaded vagrant environment so i can run vagrant commands:
   Run this command in Git bash. I run this command inside C:\users\yourusername

   git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead

NB: This will create this folder: `C:\Users\yourusername\Homestead`

With some files.

7. Still in Git bash, cd into `C:\Users\yourusername\Homestead` and run this command:

   bash init.sh

NB: this will create a folder `C:\Users\yourusername\.homestead` that contains Homestead.yaml and some other files

8. Then Generate an SSH key which you will need when you want to login to your VM by running this command:

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremailaddress@youremail.com"

NB: This will ask some question simply hit enter or type yes and hit enter.
This will create your ssh key inside `C:\Users\yourusername\.ssh`

9. Then you need to configure homestead by editing.

   C:\Users\digitlimit\Homestead\Homestead.yaml

You can right-click Homestead.yaml file then click open then choose to open with wordpad.

My Homestead.yaml looks this after editing:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /wamp/www
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
```

NB: To understand the mapping which is a process of sharing a folder between the host and the VM:

My laravel project is located at `C:\wamp\www\laravel`

This directory `/home/vagrant/Code` will be inside the VM after installation.

So what am telling VM is, whenever you see /home/vagrant/Code reference this folder  `C:\wamp\www\laravel`

Also in this:

```
sites:
        - map: laravel.dev
          to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public
```

What we are  saying here is when i go to my browser and type http://laravel.dev display the content of `/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public` which is actually pointing to `C:\www\wamp\laravel\public`

After editing Homestead.yaml file save your chnages

NB: Before we can use http://laravel.dev in the host web browser to view our laravel project, we need to add this the following to the hosts file located in

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Add this ip address under the list of other ip address listed if any:

```
192.168.10.10 laravel.dev
```

10. Finally, go back to your Git bash, ensure you are in 
    `/c/Users/yourusername/homestead` and type:

    vagrant up

Wait for vagrant to complete its processes. Click yes when you see any dialog box asking for permission to create network adapter on your system

---

**Well thats all i did. Working for me**